# Java Play2 - Allow Json RPC calls?

Tags: java, javascript, json, playframework-2.0, text-editor

I am looking for a javascript rich text editor. I tried Tinymce and ckeditor so far without any success.

It works if I write it in pure html but in play2 I just get many errors.

Well http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager:FAQ tells me that I should allow json rpc calls, is that possible in play2?

Or which text editor do you use with play2?

Comment: suggest: take a look at Aloha, it's quite easy and cool editor

Comment: Thanks this one is working flawless so far!